# How to update or select the same rows value in the table?

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2003

Table1

```
EmpID  Name  city 

101    Raja  Sydney
102    Ram   Melbourne
103    Ravi  Adelaide   
101
102
103
```

So on…,

I want to update or select the same name, city for the blank Empid’s

Expected Output

```
EmpID  Name  city 

101    Raja  Sydney
102    Ram   Melbourne
103    Ravi  Adelaide   
101    Raja  Sydney
102    Ram   Melbourne
103    Ravi  Adelaide
```

So on...,

How do I make a query for this condition?

Comment: The update is quite simple, but does this table have a primary key?

Comment: The table _as posted_ has no key and violates 1NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use sub queries to update in Access:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT tblT.EmpID, tblT.EmpName, tblT.City
    FROM tblT
    WHERE tblT.EmpName Is Null) AS t 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tblT.EmpID, tblT.EmpName, tblT.City
    FROM tblT 
    WHERE tblT.EmpName Is Not Null) AS x 
ON t.EmpID = x.EmpID 
SET t.EmpName = [x].[EmpName], t.City = [x].[City];
```

Be aware that the query design window can seriously mess up the layout and can stop sub queries from working by changing the parentheses () to square brackets [], however, it is safe enough to paste the SQL into SQL View, save and run.

Answer (score 0):

You table as posted has no key and violates [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF).

For example, if you table contained this data:

```
Table1

EmpID  Name  city 

101    Raja  Sydney
102    Ram   Melbourne
103    Ravi  Adelaide   
101    Ajaa  New York
102    Mar   Des Moines
103    Ivar  Dallas   
101
102
103
```

...then which value would you expect this query to pick for 102: Melbourne or Des Moines?